# Preprocessor / conditional variable definition

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi

The following code compiles on Arduino and on Raspberry:

```
#if defined(ARDUINO)
   const Channel channel1{1,uint64_t(0xF0F0F0F0A2LL),uint64_t(0xF0F0F0F0A1LL)};
   const Channel channel2{2,uint64_t(0xF0F0F0F0B2LL),uint64_t(0xF0F0F0F0B1LL)};
#else
    const Channel channel1{1,uint64_t(0xF0F0F0F0A1LL),uint64_t(0xF0F0F0F0A2LL)};
    const Channel channel2{2,uint64_t(0xF0F0F0F0B1LL),uint64_t(0xF0F0F0F0B2LL)};
#endif
```

Second param is the in-Channel third is the out-Channel.

With the preprocessor condition these channels (pipes RF24)) are swapped. Communication runs more or less over RX/TX (simplified). Read-channel on the client side is the write-Channel on the server side and vice versa.

This makes it possible to write the same code on the client and on the server side e.g.:

```
RF24Client client1(radio, channel1);
client1.enableReading();
...
client1.write(...)
```

Finally, my question: This works but I'm not sure if this "good style" or crap hidden behind a preprocessor expression.

I know, I know - usually you could/should solve this problem with an interface and  on the heap via pointer/smart pointer. But dynamic memory is a bit a problem on those small devices...

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the duplication and do it more like this:

```
#if defined(ARDUINO)
   #define K1 0xF0F0F0F0A2ULL
   #define K2 0xF0F0F0F0A1ULL
   #define K3 0xF0F0F0F0B2ULL
   #define K4 0xF0F0F0F0B1ULL
#else
   #define K1 0xF0F0F0F0A1ULL
   #define K2 0xF0F0F0F0A2ULL
   #define K3 0xF0F0F0F0B1ULL
   #define K4 0xF0F0F0F0B2ULL
#endif

const Channel channel1{ 1, K1, K2 };
const Channel channel2{ 2, K3, K4 };
```

You might also be able to consolidate the constants somewhat, if there is some kind of pattern.

Comment: Whoops, also need `K3` and `K4` for the values ending in `B1` and `B2`.

Comment: This was quick - thanks. Looks better then my approach. But I have 2 channels with 4 addresses: xxA1, A2, B1, B2 (each channel has 2 different addresses). I used 2 channels for this sample - real application has 5 channels...  huhhh you already saw it...

Comment: Maybe I should define a "pair-class" (can't use STL on Arduino) and do something like const myPair pair1(0x..A1,0x..B1); - leads me to my second question: A reason why you use define and not const? Memory?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Arduino programming environment - I thought it was a subset of C++ (?). Anyway, yes, there are various ways to do this - I was just making the point that [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is always a good thing to remember.

Comment: It is a subset of C++ but without STL. Anyway I just tried: #if def... const Pair<uint64_t> address1(0xF0F0F0F0A2LL,0xF0F0F0F0A1LL); #else ... # (hope you know what I mean - it works but I save just one byte per channel if I use const. OK - with define this would cost not memory at all but for the cost of type checking...

Comment: Maybe it's a bit strange but I want to see the two addresses per channel side by side (in cols)

Comment: @PaulR At the first glance your approach looked better than mine because it looks more familiar if you see a #define in a surrounding #ifdef but from the standpoint of readability... if code is also documentation - I'm not sure if it's really better - 24lines for the defines + 6 lines for the channels compared to 12 lines (based on my question)

Comment: Well matters of style do tend to be subjective - I prefer not to see repeated code though, and I prefer to see constants separated from code, but as always, YMMV.